# Create multipart form & redirect user

Tags: php, html, forms, multipart

I am fairly new to web design and need some help coding a form.  What I am looking to do is take an HTML form that contains a birthday drop down section (mm/dd/yyyy - So 3 different select tabs) and redirect a user based on their age.

If the user is under 30 send them to a new page that says we can't help them.  If the user is 30 or over, send them to a second form where they will be able to answer follow up questions... so another form.  When processed, I would need to display all the data the user has entered from the beginning of the process.

It's basically 2 form pages, and the 2nd only appears if the user is 30 or over.  I am trying to code this using PHP and can't seem to get started.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Start by learning the basics of php and HTML.

Comment: http://php.net/ should get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$interval = date_diff(new DateTime(), new DateTime($_POST['year'] .'-'. $_POST['month'] .'-'. $_POST['day']));

if ($interval->y >= 30)
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION = $_POST;
    header('Location: over30.php');
}
else
{
    header('Location: under30.php');
}
```

---

in the next form...

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<html>
    <head><head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="xxx.php">
            <input type="text" value="<?=$_SESSION['name'];?>" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  Would this allow the data to be passed if validation succeeds?  Or is that something that happens when I use enctype="multipart/form-data"?

Comment: I've added the code for passing data. now you can get the form data from `$_SESSION` in over30.php.

Comment: Thank you very much! This has definitely got me going in the right direction. I'm still stuck loading the second form though. From form A, it goes to CHECK.PHP (Your code above). If 30, goes to OVER30.PHP, which should load the second form, right? Currently, I only see the rich text of it. It loses all the CSS formatting and links. Is there a piece of code that I need to put at the top of the OVER30.PHP file to accept the values from the first form? What would you list before you declare the variables?

Comment: you're welcome! what does over30.php contains? a `<form>` only or a full page?

Comment: There is no HTML in OVER30.PHP. It's all PHP, pointing to the next form (HTML file). Then a 3rd and final PHP file delivers the results from that form.

Comment: so can I say over30.php contains nothing? if that's the case, you can change nextForm.html (should be a full page) to nextForm.php, then change to `header('Location: nextForm.php');`. and I've updated the answer which shows you how to get the form data in nextForm.php. as I've put `$_POST` data to `$_SESSION` by `$_SESSION = $_POST;`, so if you have a data called `$_POST['address']`, you can get it by `$_SESSION['address']`.